# converting a text file to a clean dataframe/tibble in R

Tags: r

I have a a text file and i would like to restructure it in R to a clean dataframe. My current text file is:

id

```
id
 Length:112630     
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

My desired dataset is as follows;

```
Variable Length Class   Mode
id  112630  character   character
```

Comment: I have not downvoted but I deduce it's because of the confusion. He uses 3 backticks to create a source code block but the content is literal text from the file. He should have used Indent by four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have Lines shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, process the file into dcf format by removing empty lines, prefacing lines with no colon with "\nVariable:", remove whitespace and use read.dcf.  (Replace the readLines command shown with the commented out one to use with a real file.)

```
library(magrittr)

# L <- readLines("myfile.txt")
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))

L %>%
  .[!grepl("^ *$", .)] %>%
  {  ix <- grep(":", ., invert = TRUE)
     replace(., ix, paste("\nVariable:", .[ix]))
  } %>%
  gsub(" ", "", .) %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.dcf %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  Variable Length     Class      Mode
1       id 112630 character character
2       id 112630 character character
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "id
 Length:112630     
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
 id
 Length:112630     
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character"
```