# Turn information in FASTA description line

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, fasta, bioconductor

I'm working with a number of bacterial CDS genomes from NCBI.  I want to create a database using the information embedded in the description line.  Here's a short snippet from such a file.

```
>lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_143053728.1_2 [locus_tag=SGR_RS00020] [db_xref=GeneID:23452906] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=WP_143053728.1] [location=3551..3919] [gbkey=CDS]
ATGACCCTTGATGACCCGACCGCGAAGGTTCGGGAAGTGATGCTCGTCGAGCGGCCCATCGGGACCCGCCTCTCCCGGTC
TCGTACTCCCGGGGGTAACAGTGCTCTCGCGCGAGATGATGACAACTCGCTCGTCACGCACGCGGTGCTCTACCCGACCG
AGGCCTTCACGGCTGAAGAAGTGGTCAAGATCGTCGGAGCTACCGCGGCTCTCGCGGCCACGGCGGGCATCGCGGTGGGC
GCAGTCGCTATGAAGGCCGGACCGCGCGTGAAGAGCACGTTCAGTGGCCTCAGGTCGAAGCTGACCCTCAAGGCCGAGGA
AGTCACAGCGGCTGCCGCTGAGCAGGTGCCGGAGCAGCCCGGCACATAA
>lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_012377421.1_3 [locus_tag=SGR_RS00025] [db_xref=GeneID:6215248] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=WP_012377421.1] [location=complement(4042..4353)] [gbkey=CDS]
ATGACCACACCATCGAGCACAGCAGCGCCCGCGCCGTTCGGCTGGTGCCACTGGCACAAAGGCCCGTCGGGGACCGCTGT
CATGGTCGACATCGTTGAGCAGAAATCGGGCCCCGGGGCTGCCCTGTACGCGTGCGCCCCATGCCGGGAGCAGCGCGGCC
TGACTCCTGTTGCCGAGCAGGCTCATGAGGTGGCCTACCGGGACTACCTGATCCACACGACGGACTGCGCCGGGTGCAGC
CGGCTAGGCCGGTGCGACCTCGGGGGCCGGCTCCGCGACGTCTACCAGAAGGCCCTGGACGGCACTCGCTGA
```

I'm reading the FASTA file in with `readDNAStringSet()`.  I'm wondering how to turn the description information using the "[term = value]" syntax in into a tibble like this

```
fasta_id, locus_tag, db_xref, protein, protein_id, location, gbk, ...
"lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_143053728.1_2", "SGR_RS00020", "GeneID:23452906", "hypothetical", ...
```

Since I'm unsure what terms will be used, I'd like to avoid pre-specifying them.

I realize I can do this using various regexp, but I figure there's a more robust and tested set of functions out there.  If so, what are they?

Comment: perhaps [key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105659/how-to-add-variable-key-value-pair-to-list-object) `setNames` approach. or more flexibly [as dcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144999/r-converting-text-with-irregular-length-into-dataframe/72145339#72145339) @onyambu answer.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the suggestions.  the `as_dcf` looks promising.

Comment: And a further `dcf`, coupled with your regexp, that appears like it would resolve some of the perceived regex headaches, such as naming `lcl|NC`, (doesn't quite cover extracting second entry of `[something=the_thing]`), and likely removing `\n`  in gbk, but, hey, it's `magrittr` magic, and I'd preferably adapt anything @g-grothendieck suggested over what I might [txt file to clean dcf/df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727701/converting-a-text-file-to-a-clean-dataframe-tibble-in-r), so in your instance, a few more steps, but a path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with

```
# could be generated using
## seq_data <- readDNAStringSet(fasta_file)
## seq_desc  <- names(seq_data)[1:3]
## 
seq_desc <- c("lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_106431650.1_1 [locus_tag=SGR_RS00015] [db_xref=GeneID:6214988] [protein=AAA family ATPase] [protein_id=WP_106431650.1] [location=944..2791] [gbkey=CDS]", "lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_143053728.1_2 [locus_tag=SGR_RS00020] [db_xref=GeneID:23452906] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=WP_143053728.1] [location=3551..3919] [gbkey=CDS]", "lcl|NC_010572.1_cds_WP_012377421.1_3 [locus_tag=SGR_RS00025] [db_xref=GeneID:6215248] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=WP_012377421.1] [location=complement(4042..4353)] [gbkey=CDS]")

## create data frame using [term = value] information.
desc_df <-  extract(as_tibble(seq_desc), value, into = "desc", regex = "[^ ]+ (.+)", remove = TRUE) %>% #remove FASTA file gene ID
    transmute(long_string = str_replace_all(desc, " ?\\[([^=]+)=([^]]+)]", "\n\\1:\\2")) %>%  #split "[term = value]" into "\nterm:value"
    transmute(dcf_string = str_replace( long_string, "^", "\n")) %>% ## add \n to start of each description
    unlist %>%
    str_c(collapse = "") %>%  #make one long string
    textConnection() %>%
    read.dcf(all=TRUE)
```

It produces,

```
locus_tag         db_xref              protein     protein_id
1 SGR_RS00015  GeneID:6214988    AAA family ATPase WP_106431650.1
2 SGR_RS00020 GeneID:23452906 hypothetical protein WP_143053728.1
3 SGR_RS00025  GeneID:6215248 hypothetical protein WP_012377421.1
                location gbkey
1              944..2791   CDS
2             3551..3919   CDS
3 complement(4042..4353)   CDS
```